# Amadeus multicity flight-search request with infants

Tags: php-curl, amadeus

In Amedeus Api call, I'm passing an infant with an Adult but it return the below error.

I'm not getting the actual mistake that how to pass an infant with an adult.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 32171,
            "title": "MANDATORY DATA MISSING",
            "detail": "Missing associated Adult Id for HELD_INFANT",
            "source": {
                "pointer": "/travelers[2]"
            },
            "status": 400
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define in the JSON body of the request the `associatedAdultId` which is to the adult traveler id who will share the seat with the held infant.

```
{
    "originDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "originLocationCode": "BCN",
            "destinationLocationCode": "MAD",
            "departureDateTimeRange": {
                "date": "2022-05-01",
                "time": "10:00:00"
            }
        },
                {
            "id": "2",
            "originLocationCode": "MAD",
            "destinationLocationCode": "ATH",
            "departureDateTimeRange": {
                "date": "2022-05-11",
                "time": "10:00:00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "travelers": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "travelerType": "ADULT",
            "fareOptions": [
                "STANDARD"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "travelerType": "HELD_INFANT",
            "associatedAdultId": "1",
            "fareOptions": [
                "STANDARD"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "sources": [
        "GDS"
    ]
}
```

You can check out the [specification](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-open-api-specification/blob/main/spec/json/FlightOffersSearch_v2_swagger_specification.json) of the Flight Offers Search API for more details.

Comment: Hi Anna Tsolakou,

Comment: how to request for fare rules..
means cancelation charges 
or detail information in one-way, round-trip and multicity

Comment: You can get the fare rules with the Flight Offers Price API. For this you will need to add the include=detailed-fare-rules at the end of your API URL as below:

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing?include=detailed-fare-rules

Comment: Thanks for reply,
let me try

Comment: {
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 404,
            "title": "No routing found for this resource/method/version combination.",
            "code": 700,
            "source": {
                "pointer": "uri"
            }
        }
    ]
}